# Real time output of an external program in PHP

Tags: php

I've written and compiled a command line program (abc.exe) that runs for about 10 mins, makes some calculations and outputs 1 line of results per 10 secs, like this:

```
C:\>abc.exe
Result 1
Result 2
Result 3
.
.
.
```

The following php script should theoretically show these results in real time, as they are produced by the program.

```
<?php 
$a = popen('abc.exe', 'r');
while($b = fgets($a)) { 
echo $b."<br>\n"; 
ob_flush();flush(); 
} 
pclose($a); 
?>
```

However, I just get all the results at the end of the execution of the program. Why could this be happening? 
Please note that if I replace `abc.exe` with `ping 8.8.8.8` or `tracert 8.8.8.8`, the script works like a charm. Please, help me, I've tried everything that is suggested in similar questions here, but nothing seems to work!

Comment: Maybe you aren't outputting and end of line character?

Comment: @dudeman Your comment gave me a hint! I changed the C code by adding `fflush(stdout)` after each printf. Now the script works as intented. Thank you!